# How can I print source code in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

example:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

**How can I print source code '{{message}}'  not  'Hello Vue!'**

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use html symbol codes instead of `{` and `}`.

```
{ = &#123;
} = &#125;  

---

{{ message }} 

&#123;&#123; message &#125;&#125;
```

Or you can use `v-text` attribute:

```
<div v-text="'{{message}}'">
</div>
```